# How to maintain the gateway IP of the Android access point?

Tags: gateway

I realized that the IP address of the access point router changes every time (Android 9).

I have to change the routing table of my device connected to the AP every time

How to freeze the IP of the AP gateway ?

Thx

EDIT:

I use my android phone as hotspot.
I connect to it from my PC equipped with a wifi key.
From my PC, my routing table for this network interface is:

Net. Dest   Netmask    Gateway          Interface         Metric
0.0.0.0     0.0.0.0    192.168.43.166   192.168.43.102    600

192.168.43.102: Is the IP address of the wifi key of the PC connected to my Android hotspot.

192.168.43.166: The gateway changes, it's never the same with each new connection to the Android Hotspot

Comment: What type of access point are we talking about? Some DSL or cable router, a Wifi bridge or a access point that connects to a mobile cellphone system?

Comment: Question is unclear if the Android device is AP or the connecting device. Android doesn't change gateway IP and even if it changes, it's communicated through DHCP to connected devices. Why do you change routing table manually? Do you use static IP configuration on connected devices? Please edit your question to add more details.

Comment: It seems that you have lost access to your account. To regain access or to merge your multiple accounts, please follow the link [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).